# Auto-insert a range into an Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

How would i insert a number of rows into a table given an incremental range, with one column of the row containing the values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
  INSERT INTO YourTable(YourColumn)
  SELECT 1 + (Level -1) * YourIncrement from dual connect by Level < TotalNumbers)

  i.e.


  INSERT INTO YourTable(YourColumn)
  SELECT 1 + (Level -1) * 1 from dual connect by Level < 100)
```

create sequence 1,2,3...99

```
  INSERT INTO YourTable(YourColumn)
  SELECT 1 + (Level -1) * 2 from dual connect by Level < 100)
```

create sequence 1, 3, 5 .. 100

Or you can use [SEQUENCES](http://psoug.org/reference/sequences.html)

Comment: How can the example you gave 1,2,3..99 work when inserting more than one column? For ex.
1,sysdate
2,sysdate

Also if using sequences, then for a range of, say 10k values, I would need to execute 10k insert commands, right?

Comment: I looked at 'INSERT INTO SELECT' and got the answer for the multi-column command :

Comment: INSERT INTO T2(ind,command)
  SELECT 1 + (Level -1) * 1,'do this' from dual connect by Level < 10;